# Error in building hello world module in kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, makefile, c

```
/*
 *  hello-1.c - The simplest kernel module.
 */

#include <linux/module.h>       /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>       /* Needed for KERN_INFO */

int init_module(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world 1.\n");

        /*
         * A non 0 return means init_module failed; module can't be loaded.
         */
        return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
```

MAKEFILE

```
obj-m += hello.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

After the `make` command I am getting the following error. What is the reason for this error and how can i resolve this?

```
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64/build M=/home/hello modules
make: *** /lib/modules/2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Do you have the appropriate kernel development packages installed? Also, I noticed that you have spaces before the `make` commands in the makefile as posted here; `make` wants commands to be prefixed by tabs. It might not be your problem at all but it's worth fixing. (That said, this question seems a better fit for Stack Overflow because it is strictly about a programming problem.)

Comment: make file is fine with tabs in it. i am aware of that.I have intalled kernel-devel packages.it seems to be some issue with build directory.can you please provide me how to create build directry properly.i hav eused command yum install kernel-devel and yum install kernel-headers i am using cent os on oracle virtual machine.

Comment: It's good that you are aware of it, but it's still a very common error and your question as posted uses spaces, not tabs, there. And you seemingly completely ignored the first part of my comment.

Comment: What do you get when you run `ls /lib/modules/`?

Comment: make sure your /lib/modules/2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64/build is exit or not. if not upgrade kernel. if u make ls -l build will shows symbolic link to your kernel source code

Answer (score 3):

-C option in make command instruct to change directory to one provided with -C. In your case, it is /lib/modules/2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64/build. But when it tries to change to that directory, compilation gives error with "No such file or directory", which means that you don't have build directory at /lib/modules/2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64/.

A lot of time it happens that build in the given path may not be a directory, but it may be a soft link pointing to a kernel source code directory.

So you need to check either there should be build directory at the required path which contains kernel source or it should be a soft link to kernel source.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all those build related comments, there are few things you have to follow while writing a kernel module. Your code will not work as you expect even after you fix those build issues. Why? you have the init and cleanup routines built, but you haven't specified/directed which one is your init routine and which is cleanup.

You have to do that this way,

at the end of the file add these two line.

```
module_init ( foo_init_fn);

module_exit ( bar_exit_fn);
```

Also, you have to specify the module license details etc. like below

```
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

MODULE_AUTHOR("Copyright (c) 2006 by xxxx xxxxx, Inc.");

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("klm_vdc");
```